# Does the operand to a fold expression need to be parenthesized?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, fold-expression

For the following [program](https://godbolt.org/z/vWW4dx):

```
#include<iostream>

auto f(auto ...args) 
{
    (std::cout << 1 << ... << args);
}

int main()
{
    f(0, 0, 0);
}
```

gcc prints `1000`, but clang gives an error:

```
error: expression not permitted as operand of fold expression
    (std::cout << 1 << ... << args);
     ~~~~~~~~~~^~~~
     (            )
```

I'm not sure I understand the error. Adding parentheses like this:

```
((std::cout << 1) << ... << args);
```

still seems to be an expression but now clang accepts this as well, and also prints `1000`.

Also, the `auto` parameters for `f` are irrelevant, the equivalent program written in c++17 has the same behavior (as shown in the demo).

So is the program valid?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The grammar of a *fold-expression* ([expr.prim.fold]) is:

> *fold-expression*:
>
> > `(` *cast-expression* *fold-operator* `...` `)`
> > `(` `...` *fold-operator* *cast-expression* `)`
> > `(` *cast-expression* *fold-operator* `...` *fold-operator* *cast-expression* `)`

You are using the third form. What you want to be parsed as the first *cast-expression* is a *shift-expression* ([expr.shift]), but a *shift-expression* is not a *cast-expression*, so this is not a valid *fold-expression*.

That is, `a >> b` has lower precedence than `(T) c`, which is the lowest precedence form that a fold expression can accept. This is because the next highest is a pointer-to-member expression, which is one of the possible fold operators itself so it could be ambiguous.

Comment: This makes sense. Probably just a gcc bug then. It does complain about other operators.